# Flutter. GoogleSignIn() instance does not have authenticatedClient() method

Tags: flutter, google-api, youtube

Following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/z4MsuZiEezY?t=251 I don't have the `authenticatedClient()` method on the `GoogleSignIn()` instance as it is shown in the video. Is this the right sequence of creating the instance and accessing the method?

```
GoogleSignIn  gsi = GoogleSignIn(
      clientId: "XXX",
      scopes: [YouTubeApi.youtubeReadonlyScope]
 );

gsi.signIn();

gsi.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) async {
  setState(() {
    _account = account;
  });

  if (_account != null) {
    final client = await gsi.authenticatedClient() // <- don't have this method on the gsi instance!
    final yapi = YouTubeApi(client);               // <- as a consequence cannot create a YouTubeApi instance
  }
});
```

Comment: There's a change to google signin i question weather or not that video is UpToDate with the current signin methods.   I think you should check the docs for updated samples https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/example

Answer (score 1):

It is an extension method.

You also need to add the `extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth` package

i.e:

```
flutter pub add extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth
```

and then:

```
import 'package:extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart';
```